# Semantic error: Unsupported calculated column name GET /dbs/*/colls/*/pkranges Kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I'm having calculated columns in my kusto query. Now one of the column name is 'GET /dbs/*/colls/*/pkranges'. While running my query I'm facing this error

```
 Semantic error: Unsupported calculated column name GET /dbs/*/colls/*/pkranges Kusto
```

Can someone help in replacing the column name dynamically or while the calculation itself?
My query is below

```
dependencies
| where operation_Id in (operation_ids)
| where timestamp > ago(7d)
| summarize duration_list=make_list_with_nulls(duration) by tostring(name), operation_Id
| extend p = pack(tostring(name), duration_list)
| summarize bag = make_bag(p) by operation_Id
| evaluate bag_unpack(bag);
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

you can replace the invalid character (`*` in this case) in the key with something else, as follows, using `replace_string()`:

```
dependencies
| where operation_Id in (operation_ids)
| where timestamp > ago(7d)
| summarize duration_list=make_list_with_nulls(duration) by tostring(name), operation_Id
| extend p = pack(replace_string(name, '*', '_'), duration_list)
| summarize bag = make_bag(p) by operation_Id
| evaluate bag_unpack(bag);
```